# How to resolve the question below using polar or cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$\oint_{c} xy ds$ where $C$ is the intersection of the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$ and $ y+z=8 $

Hi. I tried to resolve the issue below using the definition of line integral, but I couldn’t solve it. Could someone appreciate my resolution and help me finish it? Below follows what I did:

$$\oint_{c} xy ds = {\int }_{C}f\left(x,y,z\right)ds= \int_{a}^{b}f\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)\sqrt{{\left({x}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({y}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({z}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}}dt.$$

However, I could not continue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You will need to find the parametrization $\textbf{r}(t)$ for the intersection.

First, in order to be on the surface $x^2+y^2=4$, it must look like $x=...$ and $y=...$ (review parametrization of circles).

Then, in order to be on the surface $y+z=8$, i.e. $z=8-y$, we get $z=...$ (simply substitute what you got for y=).

So then $\textbf{r}(t)=...$

Comment: \begin{align*}
  x&=2\cos t \\
  y&=2\sin t \\
  z&=8-2\sin t
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)&=\langle 2\cos t, 2\sin t, 8-2\sin t \rangle \\
ds = \left\Vert\left(\text{r}\left(t\right)\right)^{\prime} \right\Vert&= \sqrt{{\left({x}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({y}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}+{\left({z}^{\prime }\left(t\right)\right)}^{2}}dt
\end{align*}

But, i need to solve using polar or cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what using polar or cylindrical coordinates on this question would mean. We are kind of using ideas of polar coordinates to get the parametrization (where we could just write $\theta$ instead of $t$). The problem can be completed using what you have.